# Swift 2.0 Finding nil when parsing from JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, null, option-type

I am trying to read from a JSON file in Swift and keep getting nil when trying to return my array.

Here is the JSON file:

```
{
"wordList" : {
    "difficulty" : "Easy",
    "list" : [
              "fireplace",
              "apple",
              "january",
              "tooth",
              "cookies",
              "mysterious",
              "essential",
              "magenta",
              "darling",
              "pterodactyl"
              ]
}}
```

I am trying to parse it with the following func:

```
func parseJSONForArrayOfWords(filepath filepath: String) -> NSArray? {
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let path = bundle.pathForResource(filepath, ofType: "json")!
    let jsonData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)!
    do {
        let JSONDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? NSDictionary
        if let dictionary = JSONDict {
            if let listWords = dictionary["wordList"] as? NSArray {
                return listWords
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("\(error)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Where "list" is the array I want returned. I keep getting nil. I would be very grateful if anybody could help me out. Thank you!

Comment: wordList is a dictionary not an array. It has 2 keys, "difficulty" and "list".

Comment: okay i see. so is JSONDict a dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: Precisely, to extract the "list" just follow the same approach you used to extract the "wordList"